# How do I set up a specific button in the recyclerView to send back the info to the MainActivity?

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView that has a button that creates a TimePickerDialog, and I need send back the time picked to the MainActivity. 
How do I send it back?(Not trough clicking the entire view, just from that button/dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your RecyclerView's adapter implement a custom interface. It's the only reasonable and adequate way.

**CODE:**

***RecyclerViewAdapter.java:***

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ButtonListener mListener;

    public interface ButtonListener {
        void onButtonClick(View view, String yourInfo);
    }

    public void setButtonListener(ButtonListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        .....
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        .....
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final Button mButton;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.favouriteButton);

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mListener != null)
                        mListener.onButtonClick(v, "Your info");
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

**Activity.java:**

```
private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
...
...

mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(yourParams...);
mAdapter.setButtonListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.ButtonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonClick(View view, String yourInfo) {
                // Do stuff with yourInfo
            }
        });
```

Define the interface callback with the parameters that you need & that shall do it. This way you can intercept the RecyclerView items' click event and handle it in your Activity (the proper way) instead of the adapter.

Comment: Can you show a example ? (it should NOT be triggered from the entire view just from a specific button )

Comment: Great! But how do I get the current position from the onBindViewHolder ?

Comment: The current position is represented by that 'i' parameter that is passed in to onBindViewHolder.

Comment: I put in: mListener.onButtonClick(v, "Your info: "+getAdapterPosition()) ,in order to send back the position.

Comment: Are you sure that it worked ? If it didn't, try v.getLayoutPosition()